# Would a program like "Folder Lock" prevent hackers from locking my files?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, folder-lock

I recently had most all my files locked by a some hacker. I had them backed up on Dropbox, but the sync also locked the files online. If I had had the Dropbox folder secured with [Folder Lock](http://download.cnet.com/Folder-Lock/3000-2092_4-10063343.html), would my files have been unavailable to the hacker?

Comment: They were locked or encrypted?  Because its not clear how a file being locked would present a problem.  The advertised program isn't going to play well with Dropbox.

Comment: Dropbox folder on my computer is password protected using Folder Lock. Works well. Files are not encrypted. Program that got on my computer was classified as Ransomware when I looked it up. Don't recall exact name of it however.

Comment: It still sounds like your files were encrypted by the Ransomware not locked.  If you are already using it, and you already know it works, then what is the question?

Comment: Doesn't dropbox have "backup" versions of the original files available?

Comment: Start over. Yes ransonware did encrypt the files. I thought you were asking if Folder lock encrypted files. Question is whether the ransomware could have done the damage to the files if they were secured with Folder Lock

Comment: @Ken - You said your files were locked.  You should clarify your question.  There is a huge difference between a file that is locked and a file that is encrypted.  One is simple to reverse the other can only be reversed if you have the key used during the encryption process.

Comment: When ransomware got on computer the dropbox folder files were not locked or encrypted. So those files are forever gone IMO. Starting anew, I have installed Folder Lock and put the dropbox folder under it. So now the dropbox files are locked, not encrypted. Hopefully never another ransomeware, but if per chance one was to get in, I was asking if being protected by Folder Lock would prevent ransomware from accessing these files and encrypting them.

Comment: Dropbox does have a way to recover the files if they are not over 30 days old. I did recover some of the more important ones.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox for Work has unlimited restore of previous versions. Dropbox Personal or Pro let's you restore up to the last 30 days. These are for files only, but in your situation, you may need to store folders to a specific point in time. Someone wrote a python script called [dropbox-restore](https://github.com/clark800/dropbox-restore) that may be what you need to perform a point in time restore.

This is all contingent upon you having your computer cleaned of the mess first.